# iPad email: How to select all messages after filtering?

Tags: ipad, email

I am trying to help my friend remove messages she no longer needs from her yahoo mail using her iPad.  I have successfully figured out how to search for all messages from a particular sender.  I have also found the "Edit" button!

Now, how do I highlight or select all of them in one fell swoop?  Currently, I am going dit-dit-dit-dit hitting the checkboxes and then scrolling down to see some more.  Very inefficient!

Comment: This is likely easier to do logging into yahoo mail in a web browser.  Mail app on the iPad uses imap, therefor whatever you do in the browser will be synced to the iPad.

Comment: @Tyson - I was wondering about imap.  Good to know. / Okay, we will use the browser on a real computer.  Good idea.

Comment: Please make the comment into an answer if it helped the user :) thanks

Comment: @Tyson - ditto what Fabrice said.  And thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely easier to do logging into yahoo mail in a web browser. Mail app on the iPad uses imap, therefor whatever you do in the browser will be synced to the iPad.